# Move pdf file from SQL database to local ASP.net

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to move the saved pdf file in my database to my local drive. I cannot find a way to do it. When I click on button1 , the dialog save or open shows up. I want to save the file directly on my local drive. Any help ?

please note that reader["FileData"] contains my file.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{


    string id = TextBox1.Text.TrimEnd();

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString =   ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();


    cmd.CommandText = "Select * From FileInformation where Id=3";// +id + " ";
    cmd.Connection = con;
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    reader.Read();

    Response.Clear();

    //Response.Buffer = true;

    Response.ContentType = reader["FileType"].ToString();
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" +       reader["FileName"] + "\"");
   Response.BinaryWrite((byte[])reader["FileData"]);
   Response.Flush();
    Response.End();           
    con.Close();


}
```

Any help on this ?

Comment: why don't you press save and navigate to your local drive?

Comment: You only have the pdf as binary data in your database or you also have the actual file in your hard drive?

Comment: I dont want the user to press Save. The reason behind that is that I want to save that file automaticaly to my hard drive somwhere , merge it with another pdf file then upload it again.

Comment: I made it :) txt me for any help.